# copy last column of one table to another table based on some condition

Tags: jquery, html

I have two tables. I want to take last column of table3 and put in to table4

eg:-  table3

```
Names          Process_id   total
construction    1           1111
construction_1  1           0000
engineering     1           2222
permitting      1           3333
```

eg:- table4

```
Names           Process_id   
construction    1005         
engineering     1005         
permitting      1005
```

final result of  table4 output will be like these.

table4 result:-

```
Names           Process_id   Total_col
construction    1005         1111
engineering     1005         2222
permitting      1005         3333
```

logic:- In table3 if process_id =1 total column values move to table4.
Based on table3.Names = table4.Names total column cell value copy to table4

[I tried something here](http://jsfiddle.net/panabakavenkatesh/7ppswrp2/)

Please help me these

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I modified your code based on your requirement.please check it once.

```
 rowCount = $('#table3 tr:last').index() + 1;
 table4rowCount = $('#table3 tr:last').index() + 1;
row = rowCount + 1;
var pivot_1 = 1001;
var loop = 0



$("#table4 tr:eq(0)").find("th:last").after("<th>Total_col</th>");
for(i=1;i<row; i++)
{

    var d     = $('#table3 tr:eq(' + i + ')').find("td:eq(1)").text();
    alert(d);

  for(j=1;j<table4rowCount; j++)
{

        var one_1 = $('#table3 tr:eq(' + i + ')').find("td:eq(0)").text();
        var one_2 = $('#table4 tr:eq(' + j+ ')').find("td:eq(0)").text();

       if( d == '1'  && one_1 == one_2)
       {  
           alert(one_1 + " " + one_2);
           //alert("hi");
           var c = $('#table3 tr:eq(' + i + ')').find("td:last").text();
           alert(c);
   $('#table4 tr:eq(' + j + ')').find("td:last").after('<td style="text-align: right;">'+ c +'</td>');
         }
}
}
```

I think these code will useful to you.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**: fixed the code to only store temporary rows if the `process_id == 1`. Also, renamed column from `process_id` to `total`.

Check my code snippet. It can be done if you loop through each row and store the data in a temporary object.

```js
//create a temporary table to store data from table3
var mytable = {};


//loop through each row of table3
$('#table3 tr').each(function() {
  //store the name in the first cell of each row
  var name = $(this).find('td:first').html();
  
  //read the process_id of the current row (second cell)
  var process_id = $(this).find('td:nth-child(2)').html();


  //store the total from the last column of each row
  var total = $(this).find('td:last').html();

  //only save these values if the process_id == 1
  if (process_id==1) {
    mytable[name] = total;
  }
  

});

//add a column in table4 to represent data from table3
$('#table4 th:last').after('<th>from table3</th>');


//loop through each row of table4
$('#table4 tr').each(function() {
  //read the name from table4 to check if it is existing in our temp table.
  var name = $(this).find('td:first').html();

  if (mytable[name]) { //does our temp. table contain a value for the name we read?
    //if yes, then append its value after the last column of the current row
    $(this).append('<td>' + mytable[name] + '</td>');
  }
});
```

```css
table,
td,
th {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  padding: 4px;
  font-family: Calibri, Tahoma;
  font-size: 12px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="table3">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Names</th>
        <th>Process_id</th>
        <th>total</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>construction</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1111</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>construction_1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>0000</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>engineering</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2222</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>permitting</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>3333</td>
      </tr>


    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>

<br>
<br>

<div id="table4">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Names</th>
        <th>Process_id</th>

    </thead>

    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>construction</td>
        <td>1005</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>engineering</td>
        <td>1005</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>permitting</td>
        <td>1005</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <div>
    <div id='result'></div>
```

Comment: where you added the condition process_id =1?

Answer (score 0):

I've forked the logic. Please check this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/karthikn_jay/d5d1wr5c/)

Columns can be moved/copied from one table to another in 2 simple steps, thead and tbody. Please check the logic.

```
function copyCols() {

    var processIdArr = ['1','2'];

    // clear last col before add
    $('.lastcol').remove();

    // copy table head
    var val = $('#testTable1 thead tr').find('th:last-child').html();
    $('#testTable2 thead tr').find('th:last-child').after('<th class="lastcol">' + val + '</th>');

    // copy table body
    $('#testTable1 tbody tr').find('td:last-child').each(function(index){

        var processId = $(this).parent('tr').find('td:nth-child(2)').text();
        if( $.inArray(processId, processIdArr) >= 0 ) {

             var val = $(this).html();
             $('#testTable2 tbody tr').find('td:last-child').eq(index).after('<td class="lastcol">'+val+'</td>');

        }
   });

}
```

**Edit:** Updated the jsfiddle with the logic to check the process id. You can also check a list/array of process ids that need to be copied/moved. Eg.

```
var processIdArr = ['1','2'];
```

PS: Here the 2nd table doesn't check columns to be matched with the columns from 1st table. So, the columns are appended on row by row basis.

Comment: Your code is blindly copying values from table3 to table4 without checking if the names match. You can fix this easily

Comment: Namely: you shouldn't have copied the row with the number `0000` to the table4

Comment: Oh, I didn't see the 'logic' mentioned in the last. Will update the jsfiddle then. Thanks for letting me know.